# Javascript doesn't work on mobile, shows empty spaces

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have created a reserve schedule which consists of a calendar and certain time. On Desktop it works perfectly, also in chrome's emulator, but it doesn't work on mobile, in my case Safari and also Chrome for iOs. The calendar days don't show up in mobile.

This is the desktop version. [image]

This is the mobile version.[image]

The javascript is filled with onclick events and they are all created based on the day, month and year the user is located. I tried removing all onclick events and it showed up fine. This is how each day of the calendar is created with the function in it.

```
<div class="calendar__day" id=day'+i+' onclick="changedate('+a+','+i+','+month+','+ finday(i,yyyy,mm) +')"><span class="calendar__date">'+ i +'</span></div>
```

Is there any workaround to make it workable on mobile also? Is it because of too much javascript or just the onclick function?

Comment: If you need more information on the code to help me, I'd gladly show you more but I felt like it was more of a theoretical question than a practical one.

Comment: You probably need to set up your machine to debug it.

Comment: What are your variables? is that html part of a `document.write` or something? why is everything `' + _ + '`? are all the variables passed into that `changedate` function numbers? if not you have some missing quotes

Comment: Are you using [features in your code that aren't available in some mobile browsers](https://caniuse.com/)? For example code I wrote recently used `fetch` that worked fine in modern d/t browsers but failed in older mobile browsers because they don't have the latest tech like `fetch`.

Comment: everything is ` ' + _ + ' ` because it is created in javascript than passed as innerHtml into html. variable `a` is just a string created `'day' + i`, while `i` is an integer in the loop used to create the dates, `finday` is a function used to change the date on the upperleft section.

Comment: I haven't used `fetch` anywhere.

Comment: if any of those variables are strings you would need to pass them into the function as a string then: `\'' + a + '\'` (escaped first and last quote around your var) as it's part of a javascript string (rather than being passed directly into the function)

Comment: the string variable is `a` and it already is a string at that point.

Answer (score 0):

After putting console.logs everywhere I found out that the function `finday(i,yyyy,mm)` which was called with the `changedate` function on click was being executed everytime a new day was created in the html. I don't really know why it happened but I implemented the `finday` function inside the `changedate` and it now works. 
I guess it was just too much javascript functions being executed for a mobile browser.